# Capture everything enclosed parentheses - regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get all the text in the parentheses from the following paragraph using regex.

The regex expression I'm currently using doesn't work as I would like because it brakes the text on the inner parentheses.

**This is the text:**

Financial Operations (Financing, Customer Payment, and Settlement (AR), Collaborative Financial Processing, Vendor Invoice Verification and Processing (AP),Bank processes and Relationship Management, Allocation of Shared Services), Accounting(Financial statements, General Ledger and Subledger, Revenue and Cost Accounting, Job and Product Accounting, Product and Service Costing ), Corporate Services (Real estate management, Travel management (TEAs), Treasury and finance management ) Human Resource Management (HR Strategy and Planning, Recruitment, Payroll, Compensation and Total Benefits, Employee Development ), Manufacturing and Logistics (Production planning, materials management, inventory management, order entry and processing, warehouse mgmt, transportation mgmt, project mgmt, plant maintenance, customer service mgmt)

**This is the regex I'm using:**
`\((.*?)\)|{(.*?)}|\[(.*?)]`

Please see the link below for an example of the problem and the current regex expression I'm using

[The regex expression I'm using](https://regex101.com/r/yFnSru/1)

Comment: I think maybe some search terms you'd be looking for are "how to match balanced parenthesis" and that turns up this seemingly valuable question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern works for your sample

```
\((?:[^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)
```

see https://regex101.com/r/bQrjXi/1